# Call a function from an external JavaScript file in href with Symfony and Twig

Tags: javascript, function, symfony, twig, external

I'm trying to call a function from an external JavaScript file in href with Symfony and Twig.

Here is my JavaScript file `pm.js` :

```
function test(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

And here is my template :

```
{# templates/pm/pm.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ parent() }} | Private messaging{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    (...)
    <a href="javascript:test({{ message.id }});">test</a>
    (...)
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/js/pm.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I do that? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are using a compiled `pm.js` javascript file (that's why it lives in `build/js`  I guess). If you just have placed `pm.js` in your public js folder without compiling it your code will be good to work as it is.

Your problem is that your function after the compilation is not a global function. You could overcome this with several ways, the most simple of them being:

```
window.test = function test(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Just assign your function test() to a window variable `window.test` and it will work.